# ReactJS nested JSON object to inputs update handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a JSON editor, which render `input` if the object is a `string`, if the object is not a `string`, it will run recursive with the object.

`Object` is either string or object that contains `strings/objects`.

```
data: {
  "title": "title",
  "description": "description",
  "errors": {
    "error1": "man",
    "erro2": "female"
  },
  "popups": {
    "main": {
      "1": "two",
      "two": "three"
    },
    "main2": {
      "2": "3",
      "tw": "tww"
    }
  }
}
```

I created the following recursive function to display it:

```
  convertData(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).reduce((arr, key) => {
      const value = data[key];
      if(typeof value === "string") {
        arr.push(
          key.includes("Paragraph") || key.includes("Description") ? 
            <textarea>{value}</textarea> :
            <input type="text" value={value} onChange={
              (e) => {
                this.setState({
                  data: {
                    ...this.state.data,
                   [key] : e.target.value
                  }
                 })
              }
            } />
        );
      }
      else {
        arr.push(
          <fieldset>
            <legend>{key}</legend>
            <div style={{padding: "20px"}}>{this.convertData(value)}</div>
          </fieldset>
        );
      }
      return arr;
    }, []);
  }
```

I tried to add a callback for `onChange` which will change the value to the given input in this object, but what it does currently if I try to modify nested inputs, it creates a new string to the root of the JSON object.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I know that what happens here is that the set state method, when you add new value, it puts the new string in the root, instead of the actual object in current position

Answer (score 0):

The `this.setState` call seems fishy in the way you copy the previous state using a reference to `this.state`. How about using the [callback version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)?

```
(e) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        data: {
            ...state.data,
            [key] : e.target.value
        }
    }))
}
```